# VC dimension of a combination of two hypothesis classes

Tags: vc-dimension

I have found this exercise and I cannot solve it:

> In $X=\mathbb R^2$, let's observe two models $H_1$ (rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes) and $H_2$ (lines). We define a model $H_3$ such that every hypothesis is a combination of one hypothesis from $H_1$ and one from $H_2$.
>
> Prove or disprove that the model $H_3$ has a larger VC dimension than the VC dimensions of the models $H_1$ and $H_2$.

From my lecture notes I know that the VC dimension of $H_2$ is $3$, and I have proven that the VC dimension of $H_1$ is $4$, but I don't know what method to use to get the VC dimension of $H_3$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combination? union/conjunction? Start by understanding the objects in $H_3$ and toying around with them to find a lower bound on the VC dimension

Comment: @Ariel I don't understand either how a object from the H3 model would look like, that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: To understand them we have to look at the formal definition of $H_3$, what do you mean by combination?

Comment: @Ariel As you can see the exercise doesn't specify what combination means, but from the wording of the exercise (one from $H_1$ and one from $H_2$) we can presume that it means the conjunction of $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Comment: I suggest asking your lecturer/ta what is meant by combination. Usually we're not talking about $H_1\cap H_2$ (which in your case is empty) but $\{h| \exists h_1\in H_1, h_2\in H_2 \; s.t.\; h=h_1\cap h_2\}$.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  The same exercise is posted here, so something has been copied from somewhere: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139171/755, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/93279/8560.

Comment: You can't solve an exercise if you don't know what it's asking you to do.